# How to install a Mac application using Terminal

Tags: cocoa, macos, terminal, installation, package

Apple suggests that prior to submitting to the Mac application store, the installation process for Macs be tested using the command

```
sudo installer -store -pkg path-to-package -target /
```

I saved the application package to the desktop and then in the terminal I sent the command

```
sudo installer -store -pkg /User/MyName/Desktop/helloWorld.pkg -target /
```

From the above command I get this

```
installer: invalid option -
Usage: installer [-help] [-dominfo] [-volinfo] [-pkginfo] [-allow] [-dumplog]
                 [-verbose | -verboseR] [-vers] [-config] [-plist]
                 [-file <pathToFile>] [-lang <ISOLanguageCode>] [-listiso]
                 [-showChoicesXML] [-applyChoiceChangesXML <pathToFile>]
                 [-showChoicesAfterApplyingChangesXML <pathtoFile>]
                 -pkg <pathToPackage>
                 -target <[DomainKey|MountPoint|DiskIdentifier|DeviceNode|UUID]>
```

I am very new to the [Terminal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_Terminal). What does this mean and how do I fix it so that I can install the application as suggested by Apple?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Probably not exactly your issue..

Do you have any spaces in your package path? 
You should wrap it up in double quotes to be safe, otherwise it can be taken as two separate arguments

```
sudo installer -store -pkg "/User/MyName/Desktop/helloWorld.pkg" -target /
```

Comment: I copied the command from the Apple doc to a note pad and for some reason that changed the spaces in between the commands. So the problem was "- store" when it should be "-store". Thanks for the help.

Comment: This command prompts for a admin password, is there any way to do it without that, or a option to pass the password in the same command... something like sudo -password ******

Comment: @Ben Thanks, it worked. But i want to pass some argument with this shell command. And i want to get this argument inside installation script in package installer .  Any possibilities?

Comment: @santhosh post a new SO question

Comment: @Ben Posted the new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28325244/how-to-pass-arguments-to-package-installer-from-mac-terminal

Answer (score 0):

To disable inputting password:

```
sudo visudo
```

Then add a new line like below and save then:

```
# The user can run installer as root without inputting password
yourusername ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: /usr/sbin/installer
```

Then you run installer without password:

```
sudo installer -pkg ...
```